# How can I make a list of the element numbers in a list that have a field that is not null?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that I  obtained that gives me all of the elements of phraseSources where the MSoftMeaning property is null or empty:

```
public class PhraseSource
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int PhraseNum { get; set; }
    public string MSoftMeaning { get; set; 
}

public static List<PhraseSource> phraseSources;

var pList = phraseSources.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.MSoftMeaning));
```

What  I would like to do is instead of getting the row, I would like to get a list or an array of all the row numbers (is it called index) where the list elements have MSoftMeaning as null.

So for example if the first and third rows have MSoftMeaning as null then I would like  to get a list looking like this (1,3) or [1,3].

Comment: What is `PhraseSource`? Include code, please: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: For what you ask, it seems to me that you have to use `x.MSoftMeaning == null` instead of `string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.MSoftMeaning)` if you want to get all `null`and you may add `ToList()` after the `Where`. Be carefull that `null` is not empty `""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
var pList = phraseSources.Select((x, i) => new {source = x, index = i}).Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.source.MSoftMeaning)).Select(x => x.index).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could first capture the indexes, then filter and then select the original indexes:

```
var pList = phraseSources
  .Select((item, i) => new {index = i, item = item}) // capture
  .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.item.MSoftMeaning)) // filter
  .Select(p => p.index) // select only indexes
  .ToList(); // or use ToArray()
```

You need to capture first the indexes with a `Select` before the `Where`, otherwise in the last `Select` you would get the indexes of the new list.

Comment: :) but I typed slower (on mobile O:)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable.Range` to generate the indices.

```
Enumerable.Range(0, phraseSources.Count)
          .Where(index => string.IsNullOrEmpty(phraseSources[index].MSoftMeaning));
```

The above will retain all the indices of the objects where `MSoftMeaning` is null, however if you want the *position* instead of the *index* i.e. *index* `0` is *position* `1` , *index* `1` is *position* `2`, *index* `2` is *position* `3` etc. as illustrated in your post then you can perform a select adding 1 to each index to yield the *position*.

```
Enumerable.Range(0, phraseSources.Count)
          .Where(index => string.IsNullOrEmpty(phraseSources[index].MSoftMeaning))
          .Select(index => index + 1);
```

The above will yield an `IEnumerable<int>` with the elements `[1, 3]`;